# pass concatenated argument to a function

Tags: javascript

I know we can pass an argument to a function like this:

```
show(myArgument);
function show(e){
    callMe(e);
}

function callMe(e){
    console.log('I got myArgument as the callMe argument');
}
```

How can I concat myArgument as `callMe` argument here:

```
show(my);
function show(e){
    callMe(e+Argument);
}

function callMe(e){
    console.log('I got myArgument as the callMe argument');
}
```

**Note:** I don't want myArgument as string like this:  `show("myArgument")`

i want it to be like this: `show(myArgument)`

Here is my original code:

```
let tutorialText = document.getElementById("tutorialText");
let tutorialSub = document.getElementById("tutorialSub");
let tutorialImage = document.getElementById("tutorialImage");

setTimeout(function(){
  show(tutorial); // we may pass `test` instead of `tutorial` in order to invoke this function `MainTextUpAnime(testText);` 
}, 1000);

//this function doesn't work 
function show(e){
  MainTextUpAnime(e+Text);
  SubTextDownAnime(e+Sub);
  ImageShowAnime(e+Image);
}
//this one works as expected
function show(e){
  MainTextUpAnime(tutorialText);
  SubTextDownAnime(tutorialSub);
  ImageShowAnime(tutorialImage);
}

setTimeout(function(){
  MainTextDownAnime(tutorialText);
  SubTextUpAnime(tutorialSub);
  ImageHideAnime(tutorialImage);

}, 4000)



function MainTextUpAnime(el){
     el.classList.add("MainTextUpAnime");
     el.classList.remove("MainTextDownAnime");
};

function MainTextDownAnime(el){
     el.classList.remove("MainTextUpAnime");
     el.classList.add("MainTextDownAnime");
};


function SubTextUpAnime(el){
     el.classList.add("SubTextUpAnime");
     el.classList.remove("SubTextDownAnime");
};

function SubTextDownAnime(el){
     el.classList.remove("SubTextUpAnime");
     el.classList.add("SubTextDownAnime");
};


function ImageShowAnime(el){
     el.classList.add("ImageShowAnime");
     el.classList.remove("ImageHideAnime");
};

function ImageHideAnime(el){
     el.classList.remove("ImageShowAnime");
     el.classList.add("ImageHideAnime");
};
```

**Here is the last update:**

I can do what I want like this but it doesn't seem good!

```
setTimeout(function(){
  show("tutorial");
}, 1000);

//this function do the job  
function show(e){

  if(e == "tutorial"){
     MainTextDownAnime(tutorialText);
     SubTextUpAnime(tutorialSub);
     ImageHideAnime(tutorialImage);
  } else if(e == "test"){
     MainTextDownAnime(testText);
     SubTextUpAnime(testSub);
     ImageHideAnime(testImage);
  }

}
```

Comment: What is `Func`, is it another function? What would "concatenating" those functions (`e` and `func`) do?

Comment: What are the values of `e` and `Func`?  Also you're `callMe` isn't using `e` at all, so that's confusing too.

Comment: Can you try to rephrase the question? It's not clear to me exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your edit doesn't clarify things. Now what does `Argument` represent? Where does its value come from?

Comment: In the text of your question, you refer to `myArgument`, but in your code you have just `Argument`. Take some time to re-word your question and the code as it is still not clear as to what you are trying to do and where many of the apparent variables get their values from.

Comment: Please provide a *concrete* example of the arguments that `show` and `callMe` are supposed to get.

Comment: guys let me clarify this with my original code...

Comment: I'm guessing the OP wants to add another argument (a string) to arguments. So if arguments is `{'id': 0}` then the show function will get two arguments - one with the object and one with the string.

Comment: The original code doesn't help. If you don't want to place quotes around any value, then you would need to pass a variable the holds the string or you could pass a function call that returns a string.

Comment: Also, in your original code, you have `show(tutorial)`, but `tutorial` is not declared anywhere. This is what we're trying to say to you, your original premise doesn't make any sense, so we can't follow you to your ultimate goal.

Comment: And, your first `show()` function doesn't work simply because `Text`, `Sub`, and `Image` aren't declared as variables anywhere. It seems that this is your issue. You must declare all variables and give them values in order to use them.

Comment: I get the impression you don't want to concatenate anything but actually pass a second argument. It seems like you want to deduplicate your code and dynamically generate the class names based on the argument that is passed in. What I *think* you want: `function UpAnime(el, prefix) { el.classList.add(prefix + "UpAnime"); }` and elsewhere: `UpAnim(tutorialText, 'MainText'); UpAnim(tutorialSub, 'SubText');`. I could be completely wrong though, your explanation of the problem and desired outcome are not clear.

Comment: You can't add strings to variable names in any programming language I know of. What you can do is to use strings to call properties inside objects or classes. So save your `tutorialText` element in the property `tutorial` inside the object `text`. Then you can refer to it inside method `show(e)` as `MainTextUpAnime(text[e]);`

Comment: Please have a look at my last update...

Comment: `show("tutorial");` will always pass the same value to `show`. Unless you show us how `show` may be called with a different value, there isn't much we can do to help. Because as it is now, I would suggest to split the `show` function into two, `showTest()` and `showTutorial()`, and simple invoke one of those instead of `show`.

Comment: I can pass `show("test");`

Answer (score -1):

You can concat arguments when you call your function (not inside it) so by

```
show(my + Argument);
```

### After question update

In your `show` function you use variables `Text, Sub, Image` which are not defined in code:

```
function show(e){
  MainTextUpAnime(e+Text);
  SubTextDownAnime(e+Sub);
  ImageShowAnime(e+Image);
}
```

this is one reason what it doesn't work. However is not good to use external variables inside function. If you want concat strings then try to use this:

```
function show(e, Text, Sub, Image){
  MainTextUpAnime(e+Text);
  SubTextDownAnime(e+Sub);
  ImageShowAnime(e+Image);
}
```

If you want to concat arrays, use

```
function show(e, Text, Sub, Image){
  MainTextUpAnime(e.concat(Text));
  SubTextDownAnime(e.concat(Sub));
  ImageShowAnime(e.concat(Image));
}
```

Comment: How do you know `arguments` is a string?

Comment: what is `arguments`?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Comment: I not operate on `arguments` object